# How to access array elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this as var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["num"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["yyyy"]=>
    string(4) "2013"
    ["mm"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["dd"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
}
```

How to access the array elements?

Comment: I am using fetch mode as ASSOC, so why am I still getting array within another array?

Newbie here, pardon for noviceness :)

Comment: $array_variablename[index]

Comment: use foreach to iterate

Comment: @user2961121: you are probably getting multiple rows from your db. But since it's only one row, it has the index. If you were to select more rows it should be clear.

Comment: Perhaps you should read up on PHP arrays: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @all

solved! i had to assign them to individual variables and pass them over an array :)

Thnx all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your array is $arr, you can do

```
echo $arr[0]['num'];
echo $arr[0]['yyyy'];
echo $arr[0]['mm'];
echo $arr[0]['dd'];
```

As you are fetching from a database, you will receive an array for each result row, and within each array will be another array of columns. you can use a foreach() loop to iterate over the data, as follows:

```
foreach($arr as $row) {
    echo $row['num'] . ':' . $row['yyyy'] . '-' . $row['mm'] . '-' . $row['dd'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the official [PHP Doc article about arrays](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php).

In your case:

```
$yourArrayVariable[0]['yyyy']
```

Will let you access the element with value **2013**.

Or if you have an undefined number of array entries you can iterate over it with either `foreach` or `for`.

```
foreach($yourArrayVariable as $key => $value) {
    echo $key , ': ' , $value , '<br>';
}
```

or if you have only numeric indeces without a gap:

```
$arrCount = count($yourArrayVariable);

for($i = 0; $i < $arrCount; ++$i) {
   echo $i , ': ' , $arrCount[0] , '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using  `echo $array[0]['num'];`  gives output as *1*

```
    $array ='your array data here';
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        echo "num: ". $value['num'] . "/yyyy: ". $value['yyyy']. " /mm: ". $value['mm'] . " /dd: ". $value['dd'] . "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @win, why not, how you said that. run this code will give output.

Comment: @win com'on buddy, just look at unaccepted answer as well. All the answers are not same, If could, even you can post better then all.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    foreach($value as $k=>$v) {
        echo $k . " : " . $v .'<br/>';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

store array in a variable like

```
$arr =array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["num"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["yyyy"]=>
    string(4) "2013"
    ["mm"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["dd"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
}
```

for access array elements you have to use following code

```
echo $arr[0]['num'];
echo $arr[0]['yyyy'];
echo $arr[0]['mm'];
echo $arr[0]['dd'];o $arr[0]['num']
```

Comment: Did you just copy and paste my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr =Array(
  0=>array(
    "num"=>"1",
    "yyyy"=>"2013",
    "mm"=>"12",
    "dd"=>"11",
  )
 );


 foreach ($arr as $value) {    
     echo "num: ".$value["num"];
     echo "yyyy: ".$value["yyyy"];
     echo "mm: ".$value["mm"];
     echo "dd: ".$value["dd"];
 }
```