# How to set border in css from option tree array?

Tags: php

I have an option in my theme settings that is made by `option tree` that is border type. now I want to say if that wasn't empty, set css for my div.
my id of border type in `option tree` is `header-1-border-top`. when I use :

```html
<?php print_r(ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top' )); ?>
```

in my php file it shows me this:

```html
Array ( [width] => 2 [unit] => px [style] => solid [color] => #8224e3 )
```

and this is where I want to set my style :

```html
<style type="text/css">
.filmview-header-1 {
<?php if (ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top' ) !== ''){ ?>
border-top: /*what put here?*/;
<?php } ?>
}
</style>
```

I don't know what should I put where I wrote `/*what put here?*/` to everything work well.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: I know the syntax of css, I don't know how to convert array to that form

Comment: `ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top')['width'] . ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top')['unit'] . " " . ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top')['style'] . " " . ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top')['color']`

Comment: @connexo That did't work. And last ')' is extra

Comment: The keys of the array entries need to be passed as strings. Changed my comment above accordingly.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240421/how-to-access-array-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output the the result of the option/array, for example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.filmview-header-1 {
<?php if (($options = ot_get_option( 'header-1-border-top' )) !== ''): ?>
    border-top: <?php echo isset($options['width']) ? $options['width'] : null,
                           isset($options['unit'])  ? $options['unit'] : null,
                           isset($options['style']) ? ' '.$options['style'] : null,
                           isset($options['color']) ? ' '.$options['color'] : null; ?>;
<?php endif ?>
}
</style>
```

Comment: wouldn't imploding create a space between width and unit?

Comment: Are you sure? I got syntax error. and you miss  `.filmview-header-1 {}`

Comment: sorry, was rushing about at home.. fixed